# Stop connections to SQL Server sa account?

Tags: sql-server, brute-force, windows-firewall

I have a sql 2008 box under a brute force attack. They are trying to crack into the SA account which is already disabled. Is there a way, with Windows Firewall, to deny all requests to log into the SA account? Right now I'm blocking them with IPs but I'm wondering if there is way to configure a custom firewall rule to block all access just to the SA account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, to my knowledge you cannot block requests to a specific account. You can block outside requests to the port that your SQL Server installation is using, but otherwise it appears that you've done about everything that you can do.